# pyspark compare column values with another column contains range of values

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

i want to compare values of one column with another column having range of reference values.

i have tried using the following code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, size
from pyspark.sql.types import *
df1 = sc.parallelize([([1], [1, 2, 3]), ([2], [4, 5, 6,7])]).toDF(["value", "Reference_value"])
intersect = lambda type: (udf(
    lambda x, y: (
        list(set(x) & set(y)) if x is not None and y is not None else None),
    ArrayType(type)))
integer_intersect = intersect(IntegerType())

# df1.select(
#     integer_intersect("value", "Reference_value"),
#     size(integer_intersect("value", "Reference_value"))).show()
df1=df1.where(size(integer_intersect("value", "Reference_value")) > 0)
df1.show()
```

The above code works if we create dataframe like following:

because the value and refernce_value columns are array_type with long_type
but if i am reading dataframe with csv then i am not able to convert to array type. here df1 is read from CSV

```
df1 is as follows df1=

category    value   Reference value

count          1        1
n_timer       n20       n40,n20
frames         54       56
timer          n8      n3,n6,n7
pdf          FALSE      TRUE
zip          FALSE      FALSE
```

I want to compare "value" column with "Reference_value" column and to derive two new dataframes where one data frame is to filter rows if value column is not in the set of Reference value.

Output df2=

```
  category      value      Reference value

    count          1        1
    n_timer       n20       n40,n20
    zip          FALSE      FALSE
```

output df3=

```
category    value   Reference value

frames         54       56
timer          n8      n3,n6,n7
pdf          FALSE      TRUE
```

is there any easier way like array_contains. I tried Array_contains either but not working

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import array_contains
df.where(array_contains("Reference_value", df1["vale"]))
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
#One can copy paste the below code for direct input and outputs

from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, size
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import split 
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sqlContext = SQLContext.getOrCreate(sc)
df1 = sc.parallelize([("count","1","1"), ("n_timer","n20","n40,n20"), ("frames","54","56"),("timer","n8","n3,n6,n7"),("pdf","FALSE","TRUE"),("zip","FALSE","FALSE")]).toDF(["category", "value","Reference_value"])
print(df1.show())
df1=df1.withColumn("Reference_value", split("Reference_value", ",\s*").cast("array<string>"))
df1=df1.withColumn("value", split("value", ",\s*").cast("array<string>"))
intersect = lambda type: (udf(
    lambda x, y: (
        list(set(x) & set(y)) if x is not None and y is not None else None),
    ArrayType(type)))
string_intersect = intersect(StringType())
df2=df1.where(size(string_intersect("value", "Reference_value")) > 0)
df3=df1.where(size(string_intersect("value", "Reference_value")) <= 0)
print(df2.show())
print(df3.show())

 input df1=
+--------+-----+---------------+
|category|value|Reference_value|
+--------+-----+---------------+
|   count|    1|              1|
| n_timer|  n20|        n40,n20|
|  frames|   54|             56|
|   timer|   n8|       n3,n6,n7|
|     pdf|FALSE|           TRUE|
|     zip|FALSE|          FALSE|
+--------+-----+---------------+

df2=
+--------+-------+---------------+
|category|  value|Reference_value|
+--------+-------+---------------+
|   count|    [1]|            [1]|
| n_timer|  [n20]|     [n40, n20]|
|     zip|[FALSE]|        [FALSE]|
+--------+-------+---------------+

df3=
+--------+-------+---------------+
|category|  value|Reference_value|
+--------+-------+---------------+
|  frames|   [54]|           [56]|
|   timer|   [n8]|   [n3, n6, n7]|
|     pdf|[FALSE]|         [TRUE]|
+--------+-------+---------------+
```